# How show value legendValueTex in amachart?

Tags: amcharts

I use 
importGraph.legendValueText = "[[value]]";

my value is 0.2, but my graph show the value 00.2.
I want show all value like this 0.2 not 00.2.

Comment: Do you perhaps have your values in data as strings formatted like this? "00.2"

Comment: No, the numbers take amchart is 0.2.

Comment: In that case we're going to need your complete chart code and data to investigate.